# Coverting string to floats using .csv file and generating Histogram

Tags: python, csv, numpy, matplotlib, python-3.5

I've been with .cvs files to generate Histogram from the data. It has data something like this

```
    102.919 103.36
    102.602 103.05
    104.106 104.57
    108.791 109.26
    104.045 104.52
    104.324 104.77
    105.106 105.57
    102.619 103.08
    102.124 102.6
```

Here's the code I have written

```
# histplot.py
        import numpy as np
        import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
        import csv

        with open('datafile.csv', 'rU') as data:
            reader = csv.DictReader(data, delimiter=' ', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
            for line in reader:
                t = float(line)
                data.append(t)
            reader.close()

# generate the histogram
        hist, bin_edges=np.histogram(data, bins=50, range=[80,135])


# generate histogram figure
        plt.hist(data, bin_edges)
        plt.savefig('chart_file', format="pdf")
        plt.show()
```

Running this code give me an error **ValueError: could not convert string to float: '102.919,103.36'**
Can someone help me in giving few ideas regarding converting strings to float using csv file.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all `with open('datafile.csv', 'rU') as data:` means that you obtain `data` as a filehandle to the file. You can use this filehandle as an iterable but you cannot append anything to it.

Second `csv.DictReader` provides access to the data as a dictionary. In this case here, I would recommend using `csv.reader`, which gives access to the data as a `list`.

Third, you cannot convert the whole `line`, may it be a dictionary or a list, to a float. You can only do that with a single element of the list. (This is where the error comes from.) Conversion to float isn't even necessary, since the reader already takes care of that.

Now, you can simply append the elements line by line to an initially empty list and supply this list to the histogram function.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

data = [] #create empty list
with open('datafile.csv', 'rU') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
    for line in reader:
        data.extend(line)

# generate the histogram
hist, bin_edges=np.histogram(data, bins=50, range=[80,135])


# generate histogram figure
plt.hist(data, bin_edges)
#plt.savefig('chart_file', format="pdf")
plt.show()
```

Let me just mention that the whole data reading can be done in a much simpler way, using `numpy.loadtxt`.
Also, plotting the histogram may be simplified, in case no further data processing needs to take place.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.loadtxt('datafile.csv').flatten()

plt.hist(data, bins=50, range=[80,135])

plt.show()
```

Comment: it give the same error like before after making the changes suggested.

Comment: I highly doubt that, since the line producing the error in the first place (`float(line)`) is not present in the changed script. If you report about an error, always include the line that throws the error.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\JINAY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\testfile.py", line 10, in <module>
    for line in reader:
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '102.919,103.36'

this this error which is returned back

Comment: Yes, but what is line 10 in this case? I do not know your line counting.

Comment: Close to impossible, if your data really looks like you say. Are you sure it doesn't have a comma instead of a whitespace between the numbers?

Comment: Yes, I am sure my data looks like this and it has whitespaces between the numbers.

Comment: Does the second option of using np.loadtxt fail as well?

Comment: I made some additional changes to the np.loadtext and it worked. Thank you for your help.